# General GeoDjango Opinion

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, geodjango

I'm forced to crawl out of my intranet and create a public GIS site with quite an extensive dataset.  All of my data is contained within PostGIS.  I started dabbling with Geoserver/Postgis/OpenLayers and find it quite easy to work with but perhaps a little more difficult to merge into a full blown website with security, etc...

So I've come across GeoDjango and I have enjoyed the python programming I've undertaken thus far.  Has anyone used a GeoDjango/Postgis/OpenLayers combination?  How fast is GeoDjango in serving data?  Do you know of any professional websites I can browse that are built with GeoDjango?  I've found it hard to find any demonstrations on the net.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Maybe you can split your question? That way people can focus on giving the best answers for each. The  StackExchange format strongly encourages only one question per thread.

Comment: Pinterest,disquss and many orher high traffic sites are built on django. It is an excellent web framework

Answer (score 5):

Rather basic answer to your interesting question.

Django is a mature web framework. Geodjango is a set of classes allowing you to edit/save/display geospatial data types via the admin module or your own web pages (by employing openLayer in the background).  This is fun/impressive but Geodjango doesn't do very much else per se.

Geoserver is a web mapping server, of course. Allows you to collate, manage, serve up and style individual layers robustly and at speed. A common requirement is to permit users to compile maps made up of one or more layers.  To my knowledge Django does not offer this; geoserver does - if you use the basic openLayers API. On the other hand Geoserver gives us little by way of developing a custom application to guide users to their data/information. We tend to use python or php scripts for this, but I'd prefer to use Django.

In summary, a combination of the two products might be worth consideration.

Lastly, it is often useful to produce and/or cache tiles (pretty raster maps based on vector input layers) in conjunction with a tile server.  Certainly GeoDjango can be used to produce one of these (e.g. Eric Westra's book) but we have started testing with TileMill (based on mapnik).

Answer (score 4):

i have used geodjango + postgis + openlayers for a client which has wanted his project on company internal server. I call them as super trio. :)  these are all so good and entertaining but some hard to code with them.

there is no problem with performence if you model your database and models in rationally way. postgis has some special spatial index method for your spatial datas. geodjango has lots of spatial lookup which can meet the needs of you. now i want to share some doc for using them in best way.

- [Introduction to Spatial Data Management with PostGIS](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.mapbender.org/presentations/Spatial_Data_Management_Arnulf_Christl/Spatial_Data_Management_Arnulf_Christl.pdf&ei=n-PBUIfBK6Sn4ATJyICYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGledqQIFWLIRXLUS-x3dT_gK7bGA)
- [Rapid Geographic Web Application Development with GeoDjango](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/4/Rapid%20Geographic%20Web%20Application%20Development%20with%20GeoDjango%20Paper.pdf)

i hope it helps you...